# Find duplicate records in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, database

How would I find duplicate fields in a mongo collection.

I'd like to check if any of the "name" fields are duplicates.

```
{
    "name" : "ksqn291",
    "__v" : 0,
    "_id" : ObjectId("540f346c3e7fc1054ffa7086"),
    "channel" : "Sales"
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 387, accepted):

Use aggregation on `name` and get `name` with `count > 1`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$group" : { "_id": "$name", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } },
    {"$match": {"_id" :{ "$ne" : null } , "count" : {"$gt": 1} } }, 
    {"$project": {"name" : "$_id", "_id" : 0} }
]);
```

To sort the results by most to least duplicates:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$group" : { "_id": "$name", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } },
    {"$match": {"_id" :{ "$ne" : null } , "count" : {"$gt": 1} } }, 
    {"$sort": {"count" : -1} },
    {"$project": {"name" : "$_id", "_id" : 0} }     
]);
```

To use with another column name than "name", change "**$name**" to "**$column_name**"

Comment: `"$match": {"_id" :{ "$ne" : null } `- is unnecessary here, since the second part of the statement would suffice filtering the result. So only checking for the group having `count > 1` will do.

Comment: Tks @BatScream. { "$ne" : null } is there just in case 'name' is null or doesn't exist. Aggregation will count null as well.

Comment: Welcome. But then why check the `_id` field. It is always guaranteed to be not null after the `group` operation.

Comment: The `_id` of a document from a `$group` stage can be null.

Comment: What will be the output of this? If i run i get all the documents what i need is i want only the duplicated id's/names.

Comment: Is there a way to also know how many duplicates per match record?

Comment: @Urasquirrel, use {"$project": {"name" : "$_id", "count":"$count", "_id" : 0} }

Comment: How can I get the duplicate data, based on two fields. Basic example: let say I've collection in which I'm storing social details like: ``` [{username: 'abc', type: 'facebook'}, {username: 'abc', type: 'instagram'}] ``` so In that case I don't want only based on username, but based on both "username & type". thanks :)

Comment: @ShivamVerma db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$group" : { "_id": {"username":"$username", "type":"$type"}, "count": { "$sum": 1 } } },
    {"$match": {"_id" :{ "$ne" : null } , "count" : {"$gt": 1} } }, 
    {"$sort": {"count" : -1} },
    {"$project": {"username" : "$_id.username", "type" : "$_id.type", "_id" : 0} }     
]);

Comment: Error: Exceeded memory limit for $group

Comment: @LucaZiegler, add { allowDiskUse = true } option:  db.collection.aggregate([..],{ allowDiskUse = true })

Answer (score 45):

You can find the `list` of `duplicate` names using the following `aggregate` pipeline:

- `Group` all the records having similar `name`.
- `Match` those `groups` having records greater than `1`.
- Then `group` again to `project` all the duplicate names as an `array`.

The Code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$group:{"_id":"$name","name":{$first:"$name"},"count":{$sum:1}}},
{$match:{"count":{$gt:1}}},
{$project:{"name":1,"_id":0}},
{$group:{"_id":null,"duplicateNames":{$push:"$name"}}},
{$project:{"_id":0,"duplicateNames":1}}
])
```

o/p:

```
{ "duplicateNames" : [ "ksqn291", "ksqn29123213Test" ] }
```

Comment: The fact that you explain what each line does makes this answer optimal.

Comment: How can I get the duplicate data, based on two fields. Basic example: let say I've collection in which I'm storing social details like: ``` [{username: 'abc', type: 'facebook'}, {username: 'abc', type: 'instagram'}] ``` so In that case I don't want only based on username, but based on both "username & type". thanks :)

Comment: is there a way to use this in such a way that I see the complete documents that have duplicate names?

Answer (score 21):

Another option is to use [`$sortByCount`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortByCount/) stage.

```javascript
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $sortByCount: '$name' }
]
```

This is the combination of `$group` & `$sort`.

> The `$sortByCount` stage is equivalent to the following [`$group`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-group) + [`$sort`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-sort) sequence:
>
> ```javascript
>     { $group: { _id: <expression>, count: { $sum: 1 } } },
>     { $sort: { count: -1 } }
> ```

Comment: is `$name` the field name? also how can you change the sorting to sort by count descending? Thanks!

Comment: To only get duplicates (as per the question), add a `$match` stage to the aggregation after the `$sortByCount`: `{$match: {count: {$gt: 1}}}`

Answer (score 15):

The answer anhic gave can be very inefficient if you have a large database and the attribute name is present only in some of the documents.

To improve efficiency you can add a $match to the aggregation.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    {"$match": {"name" :{ "$ne" : null } } }, 
    {"$group" : {"_id": "$name", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } },
    {"$match": {"count" : {"$gt": 1} } }, 
    {"$project": {"name" : "$_id", "_id" : 0} }
)
```

Answer (score 14):

```
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([  
    {$group: { 
            _id: {name: "$name"},
            uniqueIds: {$addToSet: "$_id"},
            count: {$sum: 1}
        } 
    },
    {$match: { 
        count: {"$gt": 1}
        }
    }
])
```

First Group Query the group according to the fields.

Then we check the unique Id and count it, If count is greater then 1 then the field is duplicate in the entire collection so that thing is to be handle by $match query.

Comment: haven't been able to make this one work for me too. Down voting!

Comment: This post is old but may help some one .
check this out I'll check in my local it's working. Even I came across one blog regarding this. Please have a look.
https://www.compose.com/articles/finding-duplicate-documents-in-mongodb/

Comment: I was able to get it to work - edited to update to confirmed working version.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

this is how we can achieve this in mongoDB compass

Answer (score 2):

In case you need to see all duplicated rows:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
     {"$group" : { "_id": "$name", "count": { "$sum": 1 },"data": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }}},
     {"$unwind": "$data"},
     {"$match": {"_id" :{ "$ne" : null } , "count" : {"$gt": 1} } }, 
]);
```

Comment: Error: Line 4: Unexpected token {

Answer (score 1):

If somebody is looking for a query for duplicates with an extra "$and" where clause, like "and where someOtherField is true"

The trick is to start with that other $match, because after the grouping you don't have all the data available anymore

```
// Do a first match before the grouping
{ $match: { "someOtherField": true }},
{ $group: {
    _id: { name: "$name" },
    count: { $sum: 1 }
}},
{ $match: { count: { $gte: 2 } }},
```

I searched for a very long time to find this notation, hope I can help somebody with the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you want to find duplicates regardless the case, when you want to create a case insensitive index for instance. In this case you can use this `aggregation` pipeline

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {'$group': {'_id': {'$toLower': '$name'}, 'count': { '$sum': 1 }, 'duplicates': { '$push': '$$ROOT' } } },
  {'$match': { 'count': { '$gt': 1 } } }
]);
```

Explanation:

- `group` by `name` but first change the case to lower case and push the docs to the `duplicates` array.
- `match` those groups having records greater than 1 (the duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

Search for duplicates in Compass Mongo db using $sortByCount
[screenshot]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L85QV.png