# MongoDB - Delete duplicate records

Tags: mongodb

We had an issue with some automated processing and ended up with a bunch of dupes in Mongo in a single collection. I've got 7 records where I should only have 1, but I'm not sure how to go about this 100% and looking for some guidance.

I've sorted out the query and my return records look like this:
[image: Mongo Duplicates Query]

What's the best way to remove these dupes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26984799/find-duplicate-records-in-mongodb    this might help you

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that you can fetch all the data you have, loop through every item and find all other objects with its same id. If found, delete them.

Comment: That might work out ok. If I just delete them all I can always run the import process again. I was originally thinking of other ideas based off the results of this query.